# Is it posible to use facebook graph api to list a page feed without authorizing APP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to access next

```
graph.facebook.com/pagename/feed/
```

but I don't want the app to ask the users for permissions, since this information is public available. Is it somehow posible? Until now what I get is:

```
fbtrace_id
"G69vv730PRn"
message
"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"
type
"OAuthException"
```

With an access token generated by explorer.

What I want to do is next:
A user input the page name or id, retrieve last posts, and then for each post retrieve likes and comments.

I mean can't I do something like:
http://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/pagename
and get page information?

Comment: What type of access token are you using? What permissions does it include? What is the _exact_ request you are making?

Comment: @CBroe I added information on what I want to accomplish. I'm using a user access token generated by the graph explorer.

Comment: Are you sure you're making a GET request? Because the error message rather sounds as if you might be using POST ...